# c# variable scope and initialization questions

Tags: c#, printing

I have a thorny problem here that i'm stuck with. I have some code that creates problems only after a certain number of iterations through a loop.  The code is printing some PDF files through an external PDF printer program.  The first 100 or so calls to pMgr.SubmitPrint() always work ok, but after this the PDF file that is created is corrupted.

So I have this bright idea that I need to start with a fresh instance of the objects before we run into trouble. So that is why I split up my code into two loops. After every 20 iterations through the 'i' loop, the oApprentice, DrgDoc, and pMgr objects go out of scope and the next iteration of the 'j' loop re-initializes those objects so I should be good to go. That was my assumption at least but it doesn't work that way. I still get corrupted files after a few iterations of the 'j' loop.

However, if I exit and re-start the program before my 100 calls to the PDF Printer are up, I can print as long as I want without getting corrupted files. So my question is, don't the variables I mentioned before get completely destroyed?  (They definitely go out of scope if I watch them in the debugger). What is different about exiting and re-starting the program than just re-initializing the variables?

Note that none of these objects implement the IDisposable interface so I can't use the 'using' block.

This is a winforms c# project in Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Any advice anyone?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Inventor.ApprenticeServerComponent oApprentice = new ApprenticeServerComponent();
                Inventor.ApprenticeServerDrawingDocument drgDoc;
                Inventor.ApprenticeDrawingPrintManager pMgr;
                drgDoc = (Inventor.ApprenticeServerDrawingDocument)oApprentice.Document;
                oApprentice.Open(@"C:\Vault Workspace\Designs\Main\Adapters\Alo Adapter\ADAO600 - ALO\ADAO600 - AO 990\ADAO600 - AO990 - Assemblies.idw");
                drgDoc = (Inventor.ApprenticeServerDrawingDocument)oApprentice.Document;
                pMgr = (Inventor.ApprenticeDrawingPrintManager)drgDoc.PrintManager;
                pMgr.Printer = "Bullzip PDF Printer";

                int pageCount = 1;
                foreach (Sheet sh in drgDoc.Sheets)
                {
                    if (sh.DrawingViews.Count > 0)
                    {
                        switch (sh.Orientation)
                        {
                            case PageOrientationTypeEnum.kLandscapePageOrientation:
                                pMgr.Orientation = PrintOrientationEnum.kLandscapeOrientation;
                                break;
                            case PageOrientationTypeEnum.kDefaultPageOrientation:
                                pMgr.Orientation = PrintOrientationEnum.kDefaultOrientation;
                                break;
                            case PageOrientationTypeEnum.kPortraitPageOrientation:
                                pMgr.Orientation = PrintOrientationEnum.kPortraitOrientation;
                                break;
                        }
                        pMgr.SetSheetRange(pageCount, pageCount);
                        pMgr.PrintRange = PrintRangeEnum.kPrintSheetRange;
                        pMgr.ScaleMode = Inventor.PrintScaleModeEnum.kPrintBestFitScale;

                        pMgr.SubmitPrint();
                    }
                    pageCount++;
                }
                drgDoc.Close();
                oApprentice.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: The problem probably is not in any of *your* variables. It's in the variables *in the PDF printer component*. Contact the party which developed that component.

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: I agree that the problem may very well be in the third party code.  However the chances of getting it fixed are very small. I am trying to work around the problem.

Comment: Step 1: Find a snippet of code written by the component authors.  Step 2: Place that snippet of code in a for loop that executes several hundred times.  Step 3: Modify the snippet to make it more like your own code, repeating until the snippet is identical to your own code.  Somewhere in this process, your program will stop working.  You can use "binary search for bug" to reduce the number of runs required.  This process will identify what is going wrong.  Now, that you know exactly what is causing the problem, and can fix or work around it.

Comment: A hacky solution to any bug of the form, "running this task more than X times causes problem Y" by repeatedly running the task <X times in a separate process.  This only fixes the symptoms, but sometimes is a pragmatic approach to dealing with a flaky 3rd party component.

Comment: I have done this in the past for other problems, I actually created a separate command line program, and just called it from my main code. Could you point me in the right direction on some resources to do this in a separate process within the same executable? I don't really know where to start with this.